# Regarding the new Drupal website guidance

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I'm new to Drupal and wish to work on new drupal project (Drupal 6).  It's a quiz website, a quiz with multiple options and a forum topic for each quiz.

The forum topic will be created automatically at the time new quiz is created.

How can I proceed with CCK? Can anyone help me with clue or any module to suggest?

Thanks,
Edvin :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Quiz Module](http://drupal.org/project/quiz) and the [Rules Module](http://drupal.org/project/rules) to accomplish your goals.  The Quiz Module works with many other modules such as [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck), [Views](http://drupal.org/project/Views), [Userpoints](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints), and more.

1. Download and install both the [Quiz Module](http://drupal.org/project/quiz) and [Rules Module](http://drupal.org/project/rules) to get started.
2. From there, create a rule for the event *"After Saving New Content"*.
3. Add the condition: *"Content has type"* to check for the quiz content type.
4. Add the action: *"Add new content"*. and choose *"Forum topic"* under **Content type to be used** and fill in the other options as you see fit.

For more information on using the [Rules Module](http://drupal.org/project/rules) see this link: http://drupal.org/node/298476

To learn more about Drupal you may also want to read the [Documentation](http://drupal.org/documentation)